# Does Android support 'Receiver' mode for playing audio files?

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I need to play an audio file in receiver mode(earpiece).I am not sure whether higher versions of Android SDK supports this receiver mode.I went through some links which said about 1.5/1.6 having changes in these Audio APIs and hence not sure. :(

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I believe that as long as you play your audio file using the [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), it will direct the audio to the proper place (i.e. use the ear piece output if a headset is connected etc.).</strike>

Could it be that you're looking for the [`setSpeakerphoneOn(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29) function in `AudioManager` class:

> Sets the speakerphone on or off.
>
> This method should only be used by
>   applications that replace the
>   platform-wide management of audio
>   settings or the main telephony
>   application.

Comment: Thanks Nailuj.But I was referring to earpeice, which is the one we use while hearing a call received by us. About headphones, I am using android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG to detect the same.Hope you understood what i meant. :)

Comment: @MadScientist: sorry, my bad. Updated the answer, hope I got it right this time :)

Comment: Naah...Thats alright.But I am sorry to tell you that I already tried this , but its not working...:( code as below written inside OnCreate Method...audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);It still plays in SPEAKER by default!